# Западная церковь — с прописной?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли писать словосочетание "Западная церковь" в значении "католическая церковь" с прописной буквы? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Верно: Западная церковь.

Слово церковь пишется с прописной буквы в двух случаях:

1) в значении 'Божественное учреждение' – в богословских текстах, а также если слову церковь в этом значении придается особый высокий смысл, например: Отцы Церкви, Заповеди Церкви;
2)   если слово Церковь используется вместо полного названия религиозной организации (например, вместо Русская православная церковь): решение Церкви.

В значениях 'храм' и 'религиозная организация' слово церковь пишется со строчной буквы, например: ходить в церковь, служить в церкви, отлучить от церкви, отделение церкви от государства.

В примере, который приводится в вопросе, требуется написание церковь со строчной буквы: Его преследовали церковь и правительство.

[Как писать слова, связанные с церковью?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/56-ortho)

Comment: Хм.. Мне кажется, что вопрос был про слово "западная", а не "церковь"...

Answer (score 1):

Заглянем  словари, справочники и учебники.

В большом толковом словаре:
[конфессия](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F), -и; ***ж.*** [лат. *confessio* — признание, исповедание]
**1.** Вероисповедание. *Представители различных конфессий.*
**2.** Самостоятельное, независимое от других религиозное направление, течение, ответвление. *Православная, католическая, протестантская **конфессия.***

В ПАС под редакцией Лопатина ([*Названия, связанные с религией*](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=87#pp87)):

> **§ 184.** В названиях конфессий с прописной буквы пишется первое слово, напр.: *Русская православная церковь, Евангелическо-лютеранская церковь, Украинская грекокатолическая церковь, Армянская апостольская церковь, Римско-католическая церковь.*

Из [учебника](https://www.e-derslik.edu.az/books/47/units/unit-2/page91.xhtml) по всеобщей истории:

> ***Христианская церковь в XI-XIII в веках.*** После распада Римской империи в Западной Европе главой церкви стал папа римский, а в Восточной Европе константинопольский патриарх. Между папой и патриархом шла борьба за господство над христианской церковью и раздел её доходов. В результате этой борьбы в 1054 году христианская церковь разделилась на Западную и Восточную церкви. Западная церковь стала называться католической (т. е. всемирной), а Восточная церковь — православной (т. е. «правильной веры») церковью. Обе церкви стали самостоятельными.

Пишем *Западная* с прописной буквы.